# can't get eGPU working on Ubuntu ( Aorus GTX 1070 Gaming Box )

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu-driver, thunderbolt

I recently purchased an **external GPU**, specifically the [Aorus GTX 1070 Gaming Box](https://www.gigabyte.com/Graphics-Card/GV-N1070IXEB-8GD#kf) to use with my laptop, I have a **Dell 2-in-1 XPS 13 9365** running **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**. my kernel is `4.11.0-14-generic`, when I `diff` the output of `lspci` before plugging in the eGPU to my **Thunderbolt 3** port and after I get this:

```
> 01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 15da (rev 02)
> 02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 15da (rev 02)
> 02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 15da (rev 02)
> 02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 15da (rev 02)
> 03:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 15d9 (rev 02)
```

so it seems Ubuntu has some idea i've plugged something in right?

going to 'Software & Updates' > 'Additional Drivers' tab doesn't give me any NVIDIA options, I assume this is because I don't have an internal NVIDIA card, if I run `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"` this is my output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591e (rev 02)
    DeviceName: Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Device 077a
--
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Device 9d35 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 077a
    Kernel driver in use: intel_ish_ipc
```

I figured the next step was installing NVIDIA drivers, so I did

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

but those failed to install, so then I tried going to NVIDIA's website to download the [appropriate drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/123103/en-us), i had to kill the X11 server `sudo service lightdm stop` and switch over to tty2 to go through the installation process, but this also failed, giving me errors that said no NVIDIA hardware could be found.

is this an impossible goal? is there some other way to get this eGPU working with my system?

Comment: Not an answer but I found this: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/thunderbolt

Comment: Check that you have the last Thunderbold driver with the commands `fwupdmgr refresh` and `fwupdmgr update`. I don't have any eGPU so I can't say if that works with Ubuntu or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue a few days ago, I managed to make it work, but it's unlikely my problem was the same.

If you are having this issue as of now, the reason is very likely the Thunderbolt (you can check it by the visual leds not turning on). Reason being, thunderbolt needs to be authorised by the user (or sudo, can't check I'm a sudoer and can't be bothered to).

Next issue I ran into is obviously I installed so many drivers I couldn't startx. Any X11/X.org guru would know exactly now how to repare what I did; I'm not one. So all I did is remove EVERY nvidia driver and reinstall the right one. I strongly advise to do so before rebooting if you're not kind to appreciate the tty2 at boot.

Here are a couple sources to help you on your search:

- https://egpu.io/forums/thunderbolt-linux-setup/egpus-under-linux-an-advanced-guide/

Especially this part (not the compiling a 2 year old kernel):

- http://pocketnix.org/posts/eGPUs%20under%20Linux%3A%20an%20advanced%20guide

  > If you wish to allow a recently plugged in device to be used then it
  >   is simply a matter of 'authorising' the device by locating it under
  >   /sys/bus/thunderbolt and writing '1' to the authorized file as below
  >
  > ```
  >  echo 1 > /sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/0-0/0-1/authorized
  > ```

And definitely check the section on Secure boot mode (to avoid having to enter your password every time) and Bumblebee (to dual gpu)